# Alfresco CE how to enable and configure FTP?

Tags: ftp, alfresco

How to enable and configure ftp in Alfresco Community Edition (v.5.2.0)? According to the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/adminconsole-fileservers.html) first I should configure VFS from the admin console. The documentation states

> In the Virtual File Systems section, click File Servers.

However my admin console looks like this

[image]

I am confused. Does VFS/FTP is only supported in Enterprise Edition>

Comment: That's the Alfresco Enterprise documentation that you've linked to. You need to configure it the "old way" for community, eg [this 4.x docs which should work for community + enterprise](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/fileserv-ftp-props.html)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add settings to the `alfresco-global.properties`:

```
### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=2121
ftp.enabled=true
```

and restart Tomcat

```
./alfresco.sh restart tomcat
```

V.5.1 doc: [FTP file server properties](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/fileserv-ftp-props.html)

Comment: I have successfully add `ftp.port=2121` and `ftp.enabled=true` properties in `alfresco-global.properties` and restart alfresco.
I use Repo and Share 5.1
So please suggest me how i use FTP in alfresco.