# Configuring the FTP file server in alfresco community?

Tags: ftp, alfresco

I have to download file from my file system to alfresco using FTP.
How to configure it?

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work? Did you follow the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/fileserv-ftp-intro.html)?

Comment: I have set some FTP properties in **global.properties** file

### FTP Server Configuration ###

ftp.enabled=true

ftp.port=21

ftp.bindto=

ftp.dataPortFrom=0

ftp.dataPortTo=0

ftp.keyStore=

ftp.trustStore=

ftp.passphrase=

ftp.requireSecureSession=true

ftp.sslEngineDebug=false

I am confused that which of the properties are required and what is the valid values of each properties in golbal.properties file for configuring FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alfresco CE how to enable and configure FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816401/alfresco-ce-how-to-enable-and-configure-ftp/39830228#39830228)

> Add settings to the `alfresco-global.properties`:
>
> ```
> ### FTP Server Configuration ###
> ftp.port=2121
> ftp.enabled=true
> ```
>
> and restart Tomcat
>
> ```
> ./alfresco.sh restart tomcat
> ```
>
> V.5.1 doc: [FTP file server properties][1]
>
> [1]: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/fileserv-ftp-props.html

Comment: I have already set the above properties ftp.port=2121
ftp.enabled=true
But I wants to fetch the files from my file system D:xyz to alfresco> company home>x folder.

Comment: I need to download or fetch files from my local machine to **company home **

Comment: @vikash i have same requirement as your. I want to fetch files from my file system D:/x to Alfresco > Repository > Sites > Demo. 

I also installed filezilla client. So vikash please help me how i solve it.

Comment: Have you enabled ftp in your alfresco ?